# Lightbox Jquery on click next image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, featherlight.js

I am using a mixture of freewall and featherlight plugins to produce a responsive gallery which opens into a lightbox, however, I am having the following issue with trying to get the lightbox to switch to the next image (i + 1) when clicked. 
The Lightbox image code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Einm9.png). What I want to do is to change the img src to i + 1 so it will go to the next image on click.

I also have this project on Github which might help understand: https://github.com/adamianniello/adamianniello.com/blob/master/B%C3%A6b%C3%A6l%C9%99n_Pasadena.html

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">

   var temp = "<div class='brick' style='width:{width}px;'><a href='#' data-featherlight='i/jpl/{link}.jpg'><img src='i/jpl/{index}.jpg' width='100%'></a></div>";
   var w = 1, h = 1, html = '', limitItem = 54;
   for (var i = 0; i < limitItem; ++i) {
    w = 1 + 3 * Math.random() << 0;
    html += temp.replace(/\{width\}/g, w*150).replace("{index}", i + 1).replace("{link}",i + 1);

   }
   $("#freewall").html(html);

   var wall = new Freewall("#freewall");
   wall.reset({
    selector: '.brick',
    animate: true,
    cellW: 150,
    cellH: 'auto',
    onResize: function() {
     wall.fitWidth();
    }
   });

   var images = wall.container.find('.brick');
   images.find('img').load(function() {
    wall.fitWidth();
   });
```

```html
<div id="freewall" class="free-wall"></div>
```

Comment: Are you using the `featherlight-gallery` plugin? Seems like that's what you need.

Comment: I tried using the featherlight-gallery, but I am using a Freewall plugin to show the grid, is there a way to just use the featherlight-gallery without breaking the Freewall plugin?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually trigger the next element on click on the image. Just do something like below

A function to trigger featherlight to show next image. I had assumed you initialize featherlite using `.brick a` css selector. Feel free to change this to your desired one. This function builds your next `a` tags `data-featherlight` and calls featherlight over it.

```
function showNextImage(i) {
  $('.brick a').featherlight('i/jpl/' + (((i +1) % (limitItem + 1))) + '.jpg');
}
```

Add a `onclick` in your div to call the function with current `i`.

```
var temp = "<div class='brick' style='width:{width}px;' onclick='showNextImage({index})'> <a href='#' data-featherlight='i/jpl/{link}.jpg'><img src='i/jpl/{index}.jpg' width='100%'></a></div>";
        var w = 1, h = 1, html = '', limitItem = 54;
        for (var i = 0; i < limitItem; ++i) {
            w = 1 + 3 * Math.random() << 0;
            html += temp.replace(/\{width\}/g, w*150).replace("/\{index\}/g", i + 1).replace("{link}",i + 1);

        }
        $("#freewall").html(html);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks the Freewall plugin, is there anyway to target the image (img.featherlight-image.featherlight-inner) directly? And on click change the image to the next (i +1)?

Comment: If you check the github link { https://github.com/adamianniello/adamianniello.com/blob/master/B%C3%A6b%C3%A6l%C9%99n_Pasadena.html } you can see how I used both the Freewall plugin and the Featherlight plugins to create a custom grid/lightbox